# Error while displaying base64 encoded images in an html page

Tags: html, python-2.7, base64, python-imaging-library

I have a list consisting of base64 encoded images:

When I tried to display images from the list in the HTML page, it displays only the first image continuously. When I printed each element in the list, I saw that the first encoding name is padded with the second encoding name.

For example:

If the name of the first encoded image is "first", then the name of the second encoding is "firstsecond" and the third will be "firstsecondthird" like wise it is repeating till the last image in the list.

My encoding code is :

```
img = Image.open(os.path.join(upload,filename))       
    cropped = img.crop( ( left, top, right, bottom ) )        
    cropped.save(buffer, "PNG")
    img_str = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue())
    crop_pic.append(img_str)
```

My html code is :

```
<table>
                {% for i in crop_pic: %}                                            
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ i }}">                                                              
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
 </table>
```

crop_pic is the list containing images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the name of the first image is padding with second while the loop goes on and to avoid this I deleted the variables img_str and the buffer after appending each image to the list. So the code will be like this :

```
for top, right, bottom, left in boxes: 
    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    img = Image.open("path/to/file")       
    cropped = img.crop( ( left, top, right, bottom ) )                
    cropped.save(buffer, "PNG")
    img_str = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue())
    crop_pic.append(img_str) 
    del img_str, buffer
```

so after running this code I did't got same image while displaying in the html page.